# in flutter form? can TextFormField and ListTile work together

Tags: flutter, widget

in writing forms 
is it good to put TextFormField inside ListTile in subtitle argument or besides each other
what the best way to write forms that need many inputs type if I want to keep the layout look like a list

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[example`ListTile(
                      title: Text('Event Name'),
                      subtitle: TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                            InputDecoration(labelText: 'Event Name Here'),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Invalid Text!';
                          }
                        },
                        onSaved: (value) {
                          print(value);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),`][1]

Answer (score 0):

ListTile is more used in a context of a list with items os same type, but there's no rule against using the way you are doing. Like most things in flutter it's a question of preference